# Subref with floatrow (without subcaption)

Tags: cross-referencing, subcaption, floatrow

I have subfigures created with the `floatrow` package instead of the `subcaption` package. The latter is not loaded.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\begin{subfloatrow}[2]
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{Cap1}\label{lab1}}
    {Test1}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{Cap2}\label{lab2}}
    {Test2}
    \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{Cap}
    \label{lab}}
\end{figure}
```

The display is just as I want it. The main caption has the label "Fig. 1:", the subcaptions have "(a)" and "(b)".

However, I miss the `\subref` macro of the `subcaption` package to directly link to subfigures. With `floatrow` I can only do `\ref{lab1}` yielding "1a". The former `\subref{lab1}` gave just "a" or even better "(a)" (to match the `labelformat=parens`).

Can I do something similar with only `floatrow` and `caption` loaded? And if not, how can I redefine the `\ref` macro to match the `labelformat` and thus display "1(a)" instead of "1a"?

Comment: Can you turn your code snippet into a complete, compilable example? Makes it easier for anyone wanting to help.

Comment: You should have been able to do as described in section 6.2 of `floatrow`s manual, but that doesn't work as `\newseparatedlabel` is undefined. Seems like the manual for the feature has been written, but the feature itself has not been added to the package.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. :(
The minimal example was missing, right. Sorry for that. But the answer below has one. I am still looking for a possibility to only get "(a)" instead of "1(a)"...

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it with `caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionSubType[alph]{figure}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=simple,listformat=simple}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\begin{subfloatrow}[2]
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{Caption for subfigure 1}\label{lab1}}
    {\rule{5cm}{1cm}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\caption{Caption for subfigure 2}\label{lab2}}
    {\rule{5cm}{1cm}}
    \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{General caption}
    \label{lab}}
\end{figure}

As we see in subfigures~\ref{lab1} and~\ref{lab2}, which are subfigures to Figure~\ref{lab}...

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want subfigures to appear in the LoF, change

```
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=simple,listformat=simple}
```

to

```
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=simple,list=no}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!
This will be my workaround until I find a way to really ref the subfigure displaying "(a)" instead of "1(a)".